# How to differentiate b/w manual and sensor recorded steps data in REST API?

Tags: rest, google-fit

This is how my request looks like :

URL: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

```
{
    "aggregateBy": [
        {
            "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
            "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
        }
    ],
    "bucketByTime": {
        "durationMillis": 86400000  
    },
    "startTimeMillis": 1696098600000,
    "endTimeMillis": 1696876199000
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.